# VOIP and background functionality

Tags: ios, voip, background-process, xmppframework

I need to run my app continuously in background (not periodically), while supporting iOS 6.

I ran http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios example, which runs well for a while, but after some time (i guess 10 minutes limit or 100+ pings) it crashes.

Following is the crash log

```
Application Specific Information:
BKUnsuspendLimit TheBackgrounder[5183] exceeded 15 wakes in 300 sec
```

How can I avoid this crash?

Comment: http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/ticket/1482 This info might be helpful to you

Comment: thanks looking into it

Comment: Are you testing on real device or simulator?

Comment: im using ipad for testing.

Comment: Tested on iOS 6 and iOS 7, same result.

Comment: I'm running into this now.  How did you solve it and what was causing it?

Comment: The running in the background functionality is only for VOIP apps (app that make voice calls). You either have to enable VOIP check in target settings or follow my answer. Apple will reject your app, if you are running app in background and not actually providing any VOIP services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one possible 'hack' which would allow your app to run indefinitely in background. But beware, Apple will reject your app instantly.

Pastebot looped a silent MP3 in the background to keep itself continuously active. [You can read more about that process and Apple's rejection of it here.](http://www.wired.com/2010/08/ios-clipboard-app-runs-in-background-by-playing-music/)